# Question becomes ghost at dawn?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined

I post my questions at midnight and they don't get enough attention, they just drop to second and third page before everybody wakes up. There should be a rule to prevent this.

Comment: Solution: Don't post them when everyone's sleeping.

Comment: What rule would you propose?  Stop taking new questions until it is dawn everywhere?  That means only 15 questions per day, right?

Comment: (Or call the ghostbusters)

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'll have to do a check on Joda Time / Noda Time, but I'm pretty sure it is never "dawn everywhere"

Comment: @MarcGravell very true, but I meant over the course of 24 hours, it will have been dawn everywhere.

Comment: @psubsee2003 think of the poles ;)

Comment: @psubsee2003 of course I mean North/South, not people from Poland

Comment: The problem is not with the Sun, your questions need improvement.

Comment: @psubsee2003 My solution is simple, add the 'viewed' count into the page ranking formula.

Comment: @facebook how does that help?  You still have the same volume of posts to contend with.  It's not about time of day, it is about how many questions come into Stack Overflow.  You will forever be dealing with new stuff pushing old stuff off the front page.  If you are counting on getting seen on the front page, then you are not going about it the right way.  You need to improve your questions, starting with the title, so someone would be interested enough to click on it when they see the question in the list

Answer (score 4):

I see two potential issues here, one being larger than the other.

First, **your questions could use some love.**  They're not the greatest questions, although one or two do have some well-written answers to them.

Writing a good, detailed question which is likely to be helpful to others is a good way to attract more initial attention to it.

Second, **no rule or policy would ever help a "lack of attention" issue.**  You have to note that the people that make use of the site likely have a job, or are busy at that moment, or are asleep, or are contributing to the site in their own way somewhere off to the side, so people not looking at *your* question right there and then may even be commonplace.

[Bounties exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/175248) to partially alleviate a "lack of attention" issue - the question gets placed into the "Featured" tab, and gets a bit more face time on the main page than a normal question would.  It also stands a chance of incentivizing an answer because there's a larger reputation reward attached to answering it.  That, of course, is by no means a guarantee that there will be more people giving your question attention, but it means that there's a *chance*.

Answer (score -8):

50% people in the world will be awake the time you goto bed .Dont worry.

Comment: Not necessarily true. People aren't uniformly distributed around the world, and time zones make that even less likely.