# When would be the best time for posting a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, views, timezone

Is there a time that you have noticed that has more traffic in SO (i.e. more views for a posted question)?

I suspect that due to [time zone differences](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205310/reputation-by-location) some of the questions does not get the as much views as they deserve.

This knowledge might help deciding when I should post questions in order to get a better chance for a good quality answer.

**Edit:**
I guess this will be influenced by When do users post answers (before/after/during work day)...

Comment: Avoid [midnight](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262252/2982225)

Comment: There is no best time. Just plan on setting up a bounty :(

Comment: On a serious note, you may want to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/what-is-the-ideal-time-zone-to-live-in-for-maximum-reputation).

Comment: @AviTurner : it doesn't mean, day or night. because the site is not only available for few regions. If you are at midnight, for us its might be noon.

Comment: @KumarKL Surely [some regions has more users than others](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205310/reputation-by-location), and some are more active than others. I am asking for an advice out of experience.

Comment: @KumarKL , 50% people in the world will be awake the time you goto bed .Dont worry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [The Best Time to Ask a Stack Overflow Question?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/the-best-time-to-ask-a-stack-overflow-question/), the best time to post a question in order to maximize views due to high site traffic is between around "15:00 and 22:00 GMT/UTC":

[image]

However, keep in mind that that post is about *4-5 years old*, **so the current site peak traffic may have changed** as the number of users has increased over the years.

Comment: Since it is already 2020, and the internet usage in highly populated nations like India, China and Indonesia have gone up, it might be alright to assume that posting and answering is probably higher during said nations daytime office hours timings.

Comment: I disagree. The blogpost said this graph was "the most popular to to post". I assume it means "the time when people post the most", which doesn't equal the best time to get the most views.

Answer (score 27):

The best time to post your question is now.

No, really.

Number of views is a self-correcting problem.  If you post during a quiet time, your question will stay on the front page longer, and eventually get the same number of views as that of a question posted during peak hours.

Comment: Not true because the algorithm shows posts with more views more often

Comment: @alec: Yes, but at times of low traffic, there are less posts on the front page which would otherwise push your post off the front page.

Comment: The front page isn't the only place people are viewing posts from though. Views from the front page make the post show up in other places

P.S. 3 hour reply on an 8 year old post, nice :)